# Low graphics mode error on open-source driver

Tags: xorg, fglrx, xserver

I recently did an update from Software manager, which I was holding back for a month (~250MB), it prompted me for a reboot after all the updates were installed. I rebooted into an error of Low Graphics mode and tried to diagnose the problem. Reviewing the Xserver log life I found these:

```
 (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist. Entry deleted from font path.
 (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist. Entry deleted from font path.
 (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist. Entry deleted from font path.
 (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist. Entry deleted from font path.
 (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist. Entry deleted from font path.
 (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fglrx
 (EE) Failed to load module "fglrx" (module does not exist, 0)
 (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fglrx
 (EE) Failed to load module "fglrx" (module does not exist, 0)
 (II)[KMS] Kernel modesettting enabled.
 (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
 (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
 (WW) Falling back to old probe method vesa
```

System running Ubuntu 14.04.2 64bit and GPU is an integrated graphics card AMD Radeon HD 4250. I use the default open source drivers for my system because AMD dropped support for AMD HD 4xxx on the new xorg versions above ubuntu 12.04.2, so I have no proprietary driver. I have not tweaked nor configured the open source driver. Methods I've tried to resolve my issue:

- Reinstalled open source driver
- Tried to purge `fglrx` on my ststem just to check if it really was somehow installed, no packages were found.
- Reinstalled `ubuntu-desktop`
- Purged then reinstalled `xserver-xorg`

EDIT
I've found this on the startup errors:

> (EE) Fatal server error:
>   (EE) Server is already active for display 0
>        If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock and start again
>   (EE) Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help.
>   (EE)

I tired removing it, but keep getting the same message. And according to the X.org website I ran this code on tty1 console:

> ~$ ps aux | grep `cat /tmp/.X0-lock`
>   bob    1406  0.0  0.0  16192  960  tty1    S+  17:07  0:00 grep --color=auto cat /tmp/.X0-lock

Edit 2
Received error message when finally booted into a graphical interface through recovery mode:

> ExecutablePath /usr/bin/Xorg
>   Package xserver-xorg-core 2:1.1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7
>   ProblemType Crash
>   Title Xorg cashed with SIGABRT in__assert_fail_base()
>   ApportVersion 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.10
>   CompizPlugins No Value set for '/apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins'
>   CompositorUnredirectDriverBlacklist '(nouveau|Intel).*Mesa 8.0'

Comment: It's possible Ubuntu no longer supports your graphics card. If it exists, try deleting ./.Xauthority. You'll need to enable viewing of hidden files by pressing ctrl + H.

Comment: I've tried that, no change. There was only one .Xauthority file. It was on ~/.Xauthority

Comment: Try `dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`.

Comment: No luck, might just have to do a fresh install.

Comment: You can actually upgrade, which might work. Do `apt-get dist-upgrade` to go to 14.10.

Comment: Now it doesn't even boot up into graphical, it's stuck at verbose boot.

Comment: What is the last message?

Comment: *Stopping Restore Sound Card State [OK]   *Stopping System V runlevel compability [OK], all the other starting/stopping are on [OK]

Comment: If you can get into recovery options from the GRUB menu, drop to a root prompt and run `dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: Remove that file it suggests.

Comment: I'm able to boot into recovery mode GUI but no change on regular boot. And I got an internal error window Edit 2 ^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23023/discussion-between-bob-van-elst-and-zacharee1).